# ListView seems to have trouble with UTF-8

Tags: .net, listview, utf-8

For aesthetic reasons, I'd like to replace `->` in my program with actual arrow characters (`→`). It works perfectly everywhere, except in `ListView` items, where the arrow is replaced by an empty square.

Any ideas why?

### Code (VB.Net, targeting framework 2.0):

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ListView1 As New System.Windows.Forms.ListView()
    Dim ColumnHeader1 As New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()
    Dim ColumnHeader2 As New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()
    Dim ListViewItem1 As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(New String() {"Arrow", "A → B"})


    ListView1.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader() {ColumnHeader1, ColumnHeader2})
    ListView1.Items.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem() {ListViewItem1})
    ListView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
    ListView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(205, 150)
    ListView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details

    Me.Controls.Add(ListView1)
End Sub
End Class
```

### Output:

[image: Code output]

Comment: How are you adding the character to the string? Show the code.

Comment: I've added an MWE. There's no problem when loading the same text in a simple `Label`, and it happens whichever font I select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

No repro, obviously.  Working with utf-8 in the context of ListView otherwise makes no sense.  .NET strings are stored internally in utf-16.

After question update: a rectangle appears when the font doesn't have the glyph to display the codepoint.  Troubleshoot with the charmap.exe applet.  And do make sure that you are actually reading the file correctly.  Use the debugger to inspect the string.  Use the string's ToCharArray() method to look at the individual character codes.

Comment: I've added an MWE, which doesn't load the string from an external file.

Comment: Well, chase the Font angle, as explained.

Comment: Yup, but there's no problem with the same font in other controls (`Label`, ...).

Comment: And the same problem happens with all non-ASCII characters (e.g. Chinese ones)

Comment: For some reason, I can't seem to reproduce this problem now... :/

Comment: Update on this: some users of my app reported the same problem. It seems to appear in Windows XP in particular.